# form post - how to get url

Tags: html, forms, post

hi so im fairly new to html and javascript, and im trying to create this simple calculator - user inputs hours and it returns various amounts of stuff for the user such as average hours etc.

I'm trying to use the  post method to submit the data but im confused as to how to get the url to use if im just writing the html file in sublime text? Below is the html code.

I've read numerous websites about client/server interaction but i'm still a little confused on how to go about this. Thanks in advance!

```html
<form action="????????" method="post">

  <div class="initialdata">
    Total employees in office:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="totalemployees">
    <br>Total work hours in a day:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="workhours">
    <br>
  </div>

  <!--- *************************Display table for inputting data************************* -->
  <div class="hours">
    <table>
      <tr id='addr0'>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="avgHours[]" min="0">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="avgHours[]" min="0">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="avgHours[]" min="0">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="avgHours[]" min="0">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="avgHours[]" min="0">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="avgHours[]" min="0">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="avgHours[]" min="0">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

          <!--- ***************** Add row button ******************** -->
          <button type="button" id="addrow" title="Add row" class="ar">
            Add row
          </button>
          <!--- *********************** CALCULATE button ************************** -->

          <input class="button" value="Calculate" type="submit" />
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you will build your program using javascript only , you not need to send request to server , your code will run on client machine by javascript between

```
<script>
</script>
```

tag , you need to listen to actions on buttons by `addEventListener` method